# python-2.7 - for images in folder copy them in another folder (.jpg .png)

Tags: linux, image, python-2.7

I have an Idea how to write the code but ain't sure if it is a good technique. Basically, I have a program running which places pictures in a folder for less than 1 second then deletes them. I wish to use python to quickly copy them in another folder!

My idea was (in general) while true: copy *.jpg and *.png to path  ---but then again they could be duplicates.... Any ideas? Using python2.7 on mint 17.2
Could use `copyfile(src, dst)` from shutils

If you do not want to write some code, could you give me a hint so I can try to figure? like the structure or the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with overriding duplicates? I think it is an okay solution.

So, you can start running this before the other program runs. It will always check if there are any `'.jpg'` or `'.png'` files. If it finds them, it will copy them. If it copies the same files multiple times, it is okay.

```
import shutil
from glob import glob

source = '/a/b/c/'
target = '/x/y/z/'

for f_name in glob(source +'*.png') + glob(source + '*.jpg'):
    shutil.copy2(f_name, target)
```